# Maintaining login session in android application

Tags: java, android, session, cookies, session-cookies

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. So im working on an app where the user enters a username and password and i send the form to the server using a POST request. After that point, when i try to click on a link, the server does not recogize that i am logged in. So i researched about this and learned that it has to do with handling session cookies. From what i understand, i have to get the cookie from the Set-Header header that the server gives me, and use that cookie in all subsequent POST requests by adding it to a Cookie request header. I did exactly that in my app and the server still does not recognize that i am logged in. Am i missing a step here? To add to this, i have tried testing this on a chrome plugin, "POSTMAN", where i do the initial post with the username and password, get the correct response and a cookie, then when i do the second post with the cookie as the header, i still get the message that i am not logged in. The only time that i can get a successful response from the second POST is when i do the initial log in through the actual website on chrome, then the second POST using the plugin. Then i get the correct response and the server recognizes that i am logged in. But obviously that is no help since it has nothing to do with the app, just the browser and the plugin. So why is this? How different is logging in through chrome than through the plugin or the app? Anyways, please help me out here and let me know if you want to see any of the code. All i want to know is if im missing a step in handling and sending the session cookie, because thats what it seems like. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax/ jquery to pass the data into server, try to alert if your success function has a result.

or try to use GET instead of POST.